# What happens when an object is dropped from a very tall tower?

Tags: free-fall

The critics against Copernicus and Galileo argued that, if the earth moved, then, a heavy body that was dropped from a very high tower should fall to the west of the foot of the tower. Galileo argued, however, that this body would fall slightly to the east. My first guess is that the body would fall directly under the point in which it was dropped. Who is right?

Comment: Think about it like this: Is the ball originally moving with the Earth?

Comment: does it have to do with the fact that the object rotates at a greater radius than the bottom of the tower, thus it's velocity parallel to earth is greater than the bottom of the tower?

Comment: If the body isn't in orbit, then it's rotating with the same angular velocity as the bottom of the tower, so it stays above the same point at all times.

Comment: well the book that I took the question from says that Galileo was right, the body will fall slightly to the east.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who is right?

Galileo.

This sounds a little like a homework problem. Is it? If so it should be labelled as such.

The sun rises in the east and sets in the west. Thus the earth is rotating "to the east". The earth ostensibly has a constant rotational velocity $\omega$ of about one revolution per 24 hours. That means a point at the base of the tower has a linear velocity "to the east" of 
$$
v_{tower}=R_e\omega\;,
$$
where $R_e$ is the radius of the earth.

And a point at the top of the tower (of height $H$) has a velocity "to the east" of
$$
v_{body}=(R_e+H)\omega\;,
$$
which is also the initial velocity of the dropped body.

You should be able to work out the rest on your own.

Comment: what about conservation of angular momentum that is pointed out in the other answer? Does the angular velocity of the object really increase as it falls? I doubt that...

Comment: It does. But that point is less important. You can understand why it lands "east of" the tower based on the simple picture I presented in my answer. If you want to understand how it is possible for the angular velocity to increase even though the force is purely radial you must remember that (unlike the Cartesian unit vectors) the radial and angular unit vectors change with position in space (and thus change with time for a coordinate system pinned to a moving object).

Answer (score 3):

When the ball is being held "stationary" at the top of the tower, **then** it is moving with the same angular velocity as the Earth. However, this does not mean that its angular velocity will remain constant during the drop. Indeed, it can't: because the object is moving at a nonzero radius from the axis of the Earth's rotation, it has angular momentum, and that angular momentum must be conserved. To account for the decrease in radius from the axis of rotation, the angular velocity of the object's rotation about the Earth's axis must increase. Therefore, the rotation of the object "speeds up" as it falls. Therefore, it rotates "faster" than the Earth under it, and so it falls slightly to the east.

In summary, the object lands to the **east** of the point over which it is dropped, **as a consequence of the conservation of angular momentum.**

Comment: I think the characterization "as a consequence of the conservation of angular momentum" is not the important point pedagogically. The object at the top of the tower is *already* moving to the east faster than the foot of the tower. The increase in *tangential* speed required by conservation of angular momentum due to the change in height is irrelevant for this problem since the height of the tower is tiny compared to the radius of the earth.

Comment: It's extremely important. The conservation of angular momentum bit doesn't change depending on whether one wishes to use the angular or linear formalism and is true regardless of the height of the tower. What's more, by your logic, the difference in tangential speed between the top of the tower and the base of the tower is negligible for exactly the same reason. Finally, conservation of angular momentum is an important, fundamental princple of physics, while the simple difference in original tangential velocity is not.

Comment: What's more, if we (incorrectly) pretend that the tangential velocity doesn't change, then all we're doing is approximating the final tangential velocity predicted by the conservation of angular momentum - the approximation is $R_{earth+tower} = R_{earth}$.

Comment: No. If we use the simplification I'm pointing out, we can actually come up with a solution in a simple way. Ask yourself: How many inches to the east for the tower does the mass land? Can you answer that question in terms of the height of the tower and the constant $g$=9.8m/s/s?

Comment: Yes. Saying that the tangential velocity doesn't change is just the consequence of holding $\vec L$ constant for $| \vec L | = r m v \sin \theta = r m v \sin \frac{\pi}{2} = r m v$ when we *approximate* by holding $r$ and $m$ constant; we therefore must have $v$ constant. You're answer isn't wrong, exactly, it's just approximate and ignores *why* the tangential velocity doesn't change. I'm not going to argue this with you any further, but you're wrong, end of story.

Comment: OK, I know I said I was done, but I've decided to say exactly one more thing. If we do your analysis, then the velocity at the top is $v_{top} = \frac{R+H}{R}v_{bottom}$. If we then account for the change in angular momentum, we get $v_{final} = \frac{R+H}{R}v_{top} = \left ( \frac{R+H}{R} \right )^2 v_{bottom}$. To summarize, the increase in tangential velocity yields a contribution **exactly** as significant as the original difference in tangential velocities. The approximation is unjustified. OK, now I'm really done.

Comment: You may be done, but it's still not clear that *you* can actually answer the question "how far to the east of the tower did the body land?"... Can you figure out the answer?